# css-loader failed to build in webpack

Tags: node.js, json, webpack

I am using webpack 5 and css-loader, but somehow the module build fails and I can run build with it. If I delete css-loader from use array, everything works. Can you help me figure it out? I run node v20.

I tried reinstalling node-sass, downgrading node and css-loader to previous versions but nothing seem to work.

webpack.config

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "[name].css",
        })
    ],
    entry: {
        app: "./src/index.js"
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
        publicPath: '/dist'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /|.js$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: '/node_modules/'
        },
        {
            test: /|.css$/,
            use: [
                MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                "css-loader"
            ]
        }
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        client: { overlay: true },
        static: { directory: path.join(__dirname) }
    }
}
```

error

```
PS C:\Users\prosh\Desktop\webpackTemplate> npm run build

> webpacktemplate@1.0.0 build
> webpack --mode production  

assets by status 3.9 KiB [cached] 1 asset
orphan modules 39 bytes [orphan] 1 module
./src/index.js 39 bytes [built] [code generated] [1 error]

ERROR in ./src/index.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):  
HookWebpackError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
CssSyntaxError

(1:1) C:\Users\prosh\Desktop\webpackTemplate\src\index.js Unknown word

> 1 | import './js/common';
    | ^
  2 | import './css/main.css'

    at tryRunOrWebpackError (C:\Users\prosh\Desktop\webpackTemplate\node_modules\webpack\lib\HookWebpackError.js:88:9)
    at webpack_require_module (C:\Users\prosh\Desktop\webpackTemplate\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:5067:12)
    at webpack_require (C:\Users\prosh\Desktop\webpackTemplate\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:5024:18)
    at C:\Users\prosh\Desktop\webpackTemplate\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:5095:20
    at symbolIterator (C:\Users\prosh\Desktop\webpackTemplate\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:3485:9)
    at done (C:\Users\prosh\Desktop\webpackTemplate\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:3527:9)
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\prosh\Desktop\webpackTemplate\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (C:\Users\prosh\Desktop\webpackTemplate\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:18:14)
    at C:\Users\prosh\Desktop\webpackTemplate\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:5002:43
    at symbolIterator (C:\Users\prosh\Desktop\webpackTemplate\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:3482:9)
-- inner error --
Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
CssSyntaxError

(1:1) C:\Users\prosh\Desktop\webpackTemplate\src\index.js Unknown word

> 1 | import './js/common';
    | ^
  2 | import './css/main.css'

    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\prosh\Desktop\webpackTemplate\node_modules\css-loader\dist\cjs.js!C:\Users\prosh\Desktop\webpackTemplate\src\index.js:1:7)
    at C:\Users\prosh\Desktop\webpackTemplate\node_modules\webpack\lib\javascript\JavascriptModulesPlugin.js:452:10
    at Hook.eval [as call] (eval at create (C:\Users\prosh\Desktop\webpackTemplate\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:19:10), <anonymous>:7:1)
    at Hook.CALL_DELEGATE [as _call] (C:\Users\prosh\Desktop\webpackTemplate\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:14:14)
    at C:\Users\prosh\Desktop\webpackTemplate\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:5069:39
    at tryRunOrWebpackError (C:\Users\prosh\Desktop\webpackTemplate\node_modules\webpack\lib\HookWebpackError.js:83:7)
    at webpack_require_module (C:\Users\prosh\Desktop\webpackTemplate\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:5067:12)
    at webpack_require (C:\Users\prosh\Desktop\webpackTemplate\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:5024:18)
    at C:\Users\prosh\Desktop\webpackTemplate\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:5095:20
    at symbolIterator (C:\Users\prosh\Desktop\webpackTemplate\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:3485:9)

Generated code for C:\Users\prosh\Desktop\webpackTemplate\node_modules\css-loader\dist\cjs.js!C:\Users\prosh\Desktop\webpackTemplate\src\index.js
1 | throw new Error("Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):\nCssSyntaxError\n\n(1:1) C:\\Users\\prosh\\Desktop\\webpackTemplate\\src\\index.js Unknown word\n\n\u001b[1m\u001b[31m>\u001b[39m\u001b[22m\u001b[90m 1 | \u001b[39mimport \u001b[32m'./js/common'\u001b[39m\u001b[33m;\u001b[39m\n \u001b[90m   | \u001b[39m\u001b[1m\u001b[31m^\u001b[39m\u001b[22m\n \u001b[90m 2 | \u001b[39mimport \u001b[32m'./css/main.css'\u001b[39m\n");      

ERROR in ./src/index.js (./src/index.js.webpack[javascript/auto]!=!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/index.js)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
CssSyntaxError

(1:1) C:\Users\prosh\Desktop\webpackTemplate\src\index.js Unknown word

> 1 | import './js/common';
    | ^
  2 | import './css/main.css'
 @ ./src/index.js

webpack 5.89.0 compiled with 2 errors in 405 ms
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "webpacktemplate",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --open --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "author": "magrega",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.23.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.23.7",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.23.8",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
    "css-loader": "5.2.7",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.7.7",
    "node-sass": "^9.0.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "sass-loader": "^14.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.4",
    "webpack": "^5.89.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.15.1"
  }
}
```

index.js

```
import './js/common';
import './css/main.css'
```